# OneSignal push notification to all segments

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, onesignal

I am trying to send push notification from the admin device, to all devices (segment:"ALL"). I can't seem to get it to work with this code.

```
let data = [
    "contents": ["en": "\(message)"],
    "included_segments": ["All"],
    "excluded_segments": ["None"],
    "ios_badgeType": "Increase",
    "ios_badgeCount": 1
]

OneSignal.defaultClient().postNotification(data)
```

The "None" segment exists and has 0 users in it. 
"All" has all active users.

When I post the notification I get an error

> ERROR: Create notification failed

while this does work without any problems:

```
let data = [
    "contents": ["en": "\(message)"],
    "include_player_ids":["20a32b7a-4254-4e03-a24c-13fe8bd91fff"],
    "ios_badgeType": "Increase",
    "ios_badgeCount": 1
]

OneSignal.defaultClient().postNotification(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `include_player_ids` from `postNotification` as other targeting parameters like `included_segments` require your OneSignal App REST API key.

If you need to target all users you should first make a call to your server from your app where you can safely use the [create notification](http://documentation.onesignal.com/v2.0/docs/notifications-create-notification) REST API POST call.