# OneSignal iOS SDK send notification fail Code 400

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

## What I have done:

I have created a simple iOS native App which has nothing but OneSignal initializaion codes. I installed my App on my 2 devices, device A and device B. Both devices are subscribed to my OneSignal App Console. When I send a notification from OneSignal Web Console, the 2 devices can both recive the notification.

## What I want to do:

When I click on a button on device A, device A will send a notification to device B.

## What is the problem:

I followed the OneSignal iOS SDK document and created the following function
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-native-sdk#section-sending-notifications

```
func onButtonClick() {
    OneSignal.postNotification(
        [
            "contents": ["en": "Test Message"],
            "include_player_ids": ["c00bb8a6-79da-419b-9999-e919831a5223"] // id of device B
        ],
        onSuccess: {(result) in print("success") },
        onFailure: {(error) in print("error : \(error)") }
    )
}
```

however, when I clicked the button, an error shows up in the xCode debug console:

```
2017-01-20 11:15:52.702852 my.bundle.id[2263:1201122] ERROR: Create notification failed
error : Optional(Error Domain=OneSignalError Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={returned={
    errors =     (
        "Please include a case-sensitive header of Authorization: Basic <YOUR-REST-API-KEY-HERE> with a valid REST API key."
    );
    reference =     (
        "https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/accounts-and-keys#section-keys-ids"
    );
}})
```

I was confused, because according to the OneSignal Reference document, send notification with "include_player_ids" **Does not require API Auth Key.**

https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification

And it also says:  **NEVER use your 'REST API key' in client code, it is intended for use on your system or server only.**

So what does this error mean? And what should I do?

I even copied and run this "work without any problems" code from [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160677/onesignal-push-notification-to-all-segments), but the same Authorization error still shows up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Answer

Just upgrade the SDK and the problem will be gone.

This was a bug in OneSignal-iOS-SDK `2.3.1`, this bug was fixed in `2.3.2`.

Please see their Github [Release Notes](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK/releases).

## How to avoid this kind of problems

Always run `pod repo update` before `pod install` to ensure that the pod install the latest version of the frameworks.

Thanks Kevin, Jason and Josh from One Signal Conversations to help me solve this problem.

Comment: Are you sure you are referring to the iOS SDK here? Cause the current release is 2.13.1. This recommendation does not solve the issue.

Comment: @TennyPinheiro This SO question was asked in Jan 2017, I'm sure a lot of things have changed now. Maybe you can contact OneSignal Support team or create another question in SO.